# Power consumption issue with Kernel?

Tags: kernel, power-management

I have aquired a Samsung notebook, model RV420 (Core i3 Sandy Bridge), acording with the specifications the battery should work for aproximatly 6 hours, but in fact his duration was 2 hours and 45 minutes. I read about the Kernel issue with power consumption and I found a patched kernel made by Canonical (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement). The patched Kernel version is 3.0.0-13, my Ubuntu is updated with kernel 3.0.0-14, the question is, this Kernel version has the patch applied?

I already know the commands that can be added to Grub, but some users have noticed that this damages the battery in some cases, so I not going to do this.

I don't have Windows installed on this machine, so I can't compare power consumption.

The Kernel 3.0.0-14 has the patch, or it's just the 3.0.0-13? If not, how can I install it?

P.S.: Sorry for the english.

Thanks.

Comment: The bug has been there since vers. 2.6.39 but i wouldn't recommend using a kernel that old because of your processor.

Comment: You can however use the kernels available for 12.04.

Comment: Join the club. Best bet is to wait for 12.04 as all these Kernel patches will be integrated in the final release

Comment: How can I install the 3.0.0-13 Kernel available here: http://zinc.canonical.com/~cking/powermanagement/mjgaspmfix/oneiric/ ? Or its better install the Precise Pangolin Kernel? And what packages should I install? My Ubuntu is 11.10 x64.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1):

Generally once an improvemnt is made to the kernel it is kept in and not deleted, somtimes however it can cause issues on some hardware after release so may be disabled in subsequent releases.

Until Precise is released with the 3.2 kernel (which should help) you can try some of the power saving tips from the [Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks)